# Anchor properties

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

In Qt, you can refer to the anchor lines of an element by using an expression such as `element.left` or `element.right` where `element` somehow references a parent or sibling element. For example:

```
Item {
    Text {
        text: "at right edge of parent"
        anchors.right: parent.right
    }
}
```

would anchor the `Text` element to the right edge of its parent, which in this case is an `Item` element.

However, when browsing the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item-members.html) for `Item`, there is no mention of a `left` or `right` property (just of `anchors.left` and `anchors.right`). This section of documentation includes all inherited members, so it should presumably be listed.

Are these properties just undocumented or are they somehow special references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html), they refer specific imaginary lines that goes through and around the `Item`. They are surely properties, as you can see [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickanchors_p.h#n63) in the code.

However they are kept private, probably to not mess up with anchoring. Their calculation can be found [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickanchors.cpp#n76) and the rationale behind it should be quite clear. Hence, when you are referring to `parent.right`, you are referring to the `x + width` of your `parent`.